# MODX REVO плагин formit не отправляет письма

Tags: ajax, modx, formit

логи
[2015-04-10 16:49:22] (ERROR @ /assets/components/ajaxform/action.php) [FormIt] Произошла ошибка при попытке отправить почту. Пустое тело сообщения

```
[[!AjaxForm?
                &snippet=`FormIt`
                &hooks=`spam,email`
                &form=`contactForm`
                &emailTpl=`sentContactEmailTpl`
                &emailSubject=`Заявка с сайта `
                &emailTo=`мояпочта@gmail.com`
                &validate=`orderform_name:required,orderform_email:required`
                &validationErrorMessage=`Необходимо заполнить обязательные поля!`
                &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
            ]]
```

страница action.php

```
    <?php

define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/index.php';

$modx->getService('error','error.modError');
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR);
$modx->setLogTarget('FILE');

// Switch context if need
if (!empty($_REQUEST['pageId'])) {
    if ($resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $_REQUEST['pageId'])) {
        if ($resource->get('context_key') != 'web') {
            $modx->switchContext($resource->get('context_key'));
        }
    }
}

/** @var AjaxForm $AjaxForm */
$AjaxForm = $modx->getService('ajaxform','AjaxForm',$modx->getOption('ajaxform_core_path',null,$modx->getOption('core_path').'components/ajaxform/').'model/ajaxform/', array());

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    $modx->sendRedirect($modx->makeUrl($modx->getOption('site_start'),'','','full'));
}
elseif (empty($_REQUEST['af_action'])) {
    echo $AjaxForm->error('af_err_action_ns');
}
else {
    echo $AjaxForm->process($_REQUEST['af_action'], $_REQUEST);
}

@session_write_close();
```

чанк

```
<td style="width: 580px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <h1 style="font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;"><font face="Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Заказ звонка!</font></h1>
                            <p style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px;">
                                <font face="Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">
                                    Имя: [[+orderform_name]]<br />
                                    E-mail: [[+orderform_email]]<br />
                                </font>
                            </p>
                            <p style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px;">
                                <font face="Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">
                                    Сообщение: [[+orderform_message]]
                                </font>
                            </p>
                        </td>
```

заметил вот что, на главной сверху обратный звонок такой

```
     [[!FormIt?
&hooks=`email`
&emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl`
&emailSubject=`Message from Learn MODx Revo Website`
&emailTo=`моя почта@gmail.com`
]]
                <div class=" col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="callbak_phone"><button data-target="#callback" data-toggle="modal" title="Заказать обратный звонок" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Заказать обратный звонок</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

в футере есть

```
 <!-- callback -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="callback" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="callbackLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="callbackLabel">Заказать обратный звонок</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            [[!AjaxForm?
                &snippet=`FormIt`
                &hooks=`spam,email`
                &form=`callbackForm`
                &emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl`
                &emailSubject=`Заказ звонка с сайта `
                &emailTo=`моя почта@gmail.com`
                &validate=`callbackform_name:required,callbackform_phone:required`
                &validationErrorMessage=`Необходимо заполнить все поля!`
                &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
            ]]

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- callback -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="orderForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderFormLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="orderFormLabel">Заявка на объект</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            [[!AjaxForm?
                &snippet=`FormIt`
                &hooks=`spam,email`
                &form=`orderForm`
                &emailTpl=`sentOrderEmailTpl`
                &emailSubject=`Заявка с сайта`
                &emailTo=`моя почта@gmail.com`
                &validate=`orderform_name:required,orderform_email:required,orderform_product_name:required`
                &validationErrorMessage=`Необходимо заполнить все поля!`
                &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
            ]]

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

и вот сам чанк sentEmailTpl

```
       [[!FormIt?
&hooks=`email`
&emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl`
&emailSubject=`Message from Learn MODx Revo Website`
&emailTo=`моя почта@gmail.com`
]]
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 10px"></td>
                            <td style="width: 580px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <h1 style="font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;"><font face="Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">Заказ звонка!</font></h1>
                                <p style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px;">
                                    <font face="Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000">
                                        Имя: [[+callbackform_name]]<br />
                                        Телефон: [[+callbackform_phone]]<br />
                                    </font>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 10px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

меня смущает &emailTpl=`sentEmailTpl` т.е. tpl он ставит свой

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста листинг чанка `sentContactEmailTpl`

Comment: добавил нужный чанк

Comment: В чанке sentEmailTpl идет вызов Formit? о_О

Answer (score 1):

sentEmailTpl должен выглядеть примерно так:

Имя: `[[+колбэкфром_нейм]]`

Телефон: `[[+колбэкфром_фон]]`

Comment: `<br>` это была часть форматирования или ответа?